# STREAM_FAILED Query Error - Connection String Cannot Be Parsed

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, fabric

I’m currently working on a data pipeline where my source is EventHub, and my sink is a Lakehouse in Microsoft Fabric. I’m trying to perform a write operation in Fabric, but I’m encountering the following error:

> [STREAM_FAILED] Query [id = b8baa874-3947-4014-83de-8e51e74e6568,
> runId = ba66b9fe-fafe-4ae3-9613-260262a6717d] terminated with
> exception: Connection String cannot be parsed.

I’m simply copying the connection string from the EventHub, which is in this format:

> "Endpoint=sb://dev-abc-eventhub.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=;SharedAccessKey=;EntityPath="

I’ve checked the connection string for any possible errors, but it seems to be correct. I’m not sure why the connection string cannot be parsed. Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.